# In some case I found (NaN==NaN) is false. How it happen?

Tags: javascript

In this case I found NaN==NaN is false. I don't understand why this is happen because of both type is number and value is same. So how it possible.

Comment: I wonder which cases you found when this was true???

Comment: You will probably find `isNaN(num)` useful. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) for details.

Comment: try it.... alert(NaN == NaN) will always be false.. Not in some cases, in all...

Comment: Although either side of `NaN==NaN` contains the same value and their type is `Number` but they are not same. According to ECMA-262, either side of `==` or `===` contains `NaN` then it will result false value.

you may find a details rules in here-

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NaN's are unusual case. They are not equal to anything (to itself too).

So, it returns false when you test `NaN==NaN`.

To test the NaN you can use as @Bergi commented:

```
var x = NaN;
if(x !== x){
  console.log('It is NaN');
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's just Javascript. I think this is pretty common, and may even be required by IEEE-754.

Answer (score 1):

Treat this as NaN is **UNKNOWN** so,

> UNKNOWN can never be same as another
>   UNKNOWN....UNKNOWN(NaN)==UNKNOWN(NaN)//false

another example:

> Lets say x='a', y='b' both are not numbers so x=NaN, y=NaN but x!=y

http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.6.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

The IEEE 754 spec for floating-point numbers (which is used by all languages for floating-point) says that NaNs are never equal.

Answer (score 1):

`NaN's` are never equal to each other by design.

```
Math.log(-1) is NaN

Math.log(-2) is NaN
```

does that mean that `Math.log(-1) == Math.log(-2)`?

Answer (score 0):

[Nan - JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN) what a beautiful case.

> Testing against NaN
>
> Equality operator (== and ===) cannot be used to test a value against
>   NaN. Use Number.isNaN() or isNaN() instead.
>
> ```
>   NaN === NaN;        // false 
>   Number.NaN === NaN; // false 
>   isNaN(NaN);         // true 
>   isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true
> ```

Comment: You can easily test for NaN using an equality operator: `x !== x` :-)

Comment: The education continues